# Несколько коллекций в myMap.geoObjects

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Я добавляю в myMap.geoObjects несколько своих коллекций

```html
myMap.geoObjects.add(myLightboxes);
myMap.geoObjects.add(myVideoracks);
myMap.geoObjects.add(myScreens);
```

myMap.geoObjects.getLength();
выдает мне 3, хотя в общем объектов во всех трех коллекциях 64.
Хотелось бы понять, почему? И как обратиться к необходимому объекту коллекции geoObjects?

Comment: Под "несколько своих коллекций" имеете ввиду GeoObjectCollection ? Если до, то вы можете пройтись по myMap.geoObjects (получите 3 своих коллекции) и далее пройтись по каждой из них

Comment: Да, GeoObjectCollection. Не могли бы вы в виде кода показать то, что имеете в виду? Мне кажется, я что-то делаю не так.

Comment: Ответил, но выглядит как нежелание разобраться самому.

Answer (score 1):

У каждой коллекции есть метод для итерации по ней. Т.е. вам нужно сперва проитерироваться по геобъектам карты, далее по каждой полученной коллекции и так до необходимого вам уровня (т.к. в коллекции могут лежать другие коллекции)

В простом случаи код может выглядеть так:

```
// Получаем объекты размещенные на карте
myMap.geoObjects.each(function (geoCollection, i) {
   // Далее проходимся по каждой из коллекции и получаем наши геобъекты
   geoCollection.each(function (geoObject, i) {
     console.log('geoObj', geoObject);
   })
});
```

В более сложном случаи, если мы имеем разные типы геобъектов и вложенные коллекции:

```
function getGeoObjects(item, akk) {
    if (item.each) {
        item.each(function (elem, i) {
            getGeoObjects(elem, akk); 
        });
    } else {
        akk.push(item);
    }

    return akk;
}

const geoObjects = getGeoObjects(myMap.geoObjects, []);
```